# BVPH Package 2.0

Tags: differential-equations, packages, boundary-condition-at-infinity

Hopefully you guys can help with this issue.

I am currently using Mathematica package [BVPH2.0](https://numericaltank.sjtu.edu.cn/BVPh2_0.htm) to solve hybrid nanofluid in boundary layer flow problem using homotopy analysis method. But I seem to have a problem with the output. The output always produces "GetConstants:There is no solution". I have used the HYBRID parameter but it does not work. I have tried substitute the values of the physical parameter into the governing equation too and the output is still the same.

Here I attach the code text of the package and my input.

Link to the package: https://numericaltank.sjtu.edu.cn/BVPh2_0/BVPh2_0.zip

### INPUT

```
(*     Filename: hcurvesB4.wl   *)
Print["The input file",$InputFileName," is loaded !"];

(*    Define the governing equation    *)
TypeEQ=1;
NumEQ=2;
f[1,z_,{f_,g_},Lambda_]:=A1*(f*D[f,{z,2}]-D[f,z]^2+1)+A2*D[f,{z,3}]+A3*M*(1-D[f,z])+(A6/A1)*Gr*g;
f[2,z_,{f_,g_},Lambda_]:=(f*D[g,z])-(2*D[f,z]*g)+(A5/A4)*(D[g,{z,2}]/Pr)+(Ec/A4)*(A2*D[f,{z,2}]^2+A3*M*(D[f,z]-1)^2);

(*    Define Boundary Conditions    *)
NumBC=5;
BC[1,z_,{f_,g_}]:=f/.z->0;
BC[2,z_,{f_,g_}]:=(D[f,z]-lamb-(A2/A1)*d*D[f,{z,2}])/.z->0;
BC[3,z_,{f_,g_}]:=(D[f,z]-1)/.z->infinity;
BC[4,z_,{f_,g_}]:=g/.z->0;
BC[5,z_,{f_,g_}]:=g/.z->infinity;

(*    Solution interval and integral interval for error    *)
zL[1]=0;   zR[1]=infinity;
zL[2]=0;   zR[2]=infinity;
zRintegral[1]=10;
zRintegral[2]=10;

(*    Define initial guess   *)
U[1,0]=(1-Exp[-z])/(lamb+d*(A2/A1));
U[2,0]=Exp[-z];

(*     Define the Auxiliary Linear Operator   *)
L[1,u_]:=D[u,{z,3}]-D[u,z];
L[2,u_]:=D[u,{z,2}]-u;

(*    Define A1-6   *)
A1=(1-ph2)*(1-ph1+ph1*(r1/r3))+(ph2*(r2/r3));
A2=1/((1-ph1)^2.5*(1-ph2)^2.5);
A3=(s2+2sb+2ph2*(s2-sf))/(s2+2sb-ph2*(s2-sf))*((s1+2sf+2ph1*(s1-sf))/(s1+2sf-ph1*(s1-sf)));
A4=(1-ph2)*(1-ph1+ph1*((r1*h2)/(r3*h3))+ph2*((r2*h2)/(r3*h3)));
A5=(k2+2kb+2ph2*(k2-kf))/(k2+2kb-ph2*(k2-kf))*((k1+2kf+2ph1*(k1-kf))/(k1+2kf-ph1*(k1-kf)));
A6=(1-ph2)*(1-ph1+ph1*((r1*b1)/(r3*b3)))+ph2*((r2*b2)/(r3*b3));

(* Define physical parameters   *)
ph1=1/10;        lamb=1/2;
ph2=1/25;        d=1;
r1=3974;         s1=1/10000000000;
r2=8933;         s2=59600000;
r3=9971/10;      sb=sf=1/20;
b1=17/2000000;   h1=765;
b2=107/10000000; h2=385;
b3=21/100000;    h3=4174;
k1=40;           M=2;
k2=401;          Pr=31/5;
kb=613/1000;     Ec=1/10;
kf=613/1000;     Gr=-1;

(*  Get optimal c0  *)
GetOptiVar[5,{},{c0[1],c0[2]}];

(*    Gain nth-order HAM Approximation    *)
BVPh[1,10];
```

Comment: I suggest contacting the author (*sjliao@sjtu.edu.cn*), since this is likely not a *Mathematica* issue per se.

Comment: Okay sir, I will contact the author.

Comment: Is `BVPh` necessary for you? I haven't yet managed to fix your code, but succeeded in using `NDSolve` to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes BVPh is necessary for me because I focus on this homotopy analysis method. So the problem can be solved using NDSolve, which means it can be solved.

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in the comment or I won't get the reminder. (As to the usuage of @ , you may want to read this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284701 ) Well, then the only thing I found is, the initial guess seems to be related. If we use `U[1, 0] = z; U[2, 0] = 9/800 E^(-3 z) z;` as the initial guess, the package produces solutions, but these solutions don't look great. (BTW, just tested with finite difference method, the solution agrees well with that produced by `NDSolve`. )

Comment: I see, I'll try to look at the initial guess. Wow, great info! Maybe I can try to use the finite difference method and NDSolve to solve the problem. Thank you so much Sir for the great solution. @xzczd